# The request of PHP cURL produces 403

Tags: php, php-curl

I have got a problem with a PHP cURL request, it displays the 403 error.

In Postman and a browser the URL works fine and Postman produced the PHP cURL code which is below but show 403 error anyway. I guess there is a cookie being generated in the same call, but `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` is not working. Can anyone please help with the code below to get a JSON data? Many thanks.

```php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.britishairways.com/solr/lpbd/lpfdestinations?fq=departure_city:LON+AND+arr_city_name_search:***+AND+trip_type:RT+AND+number_of_nights:7+AND+cabin:M&facet.pivot=arrival_city,is_sales_fare&facet=true',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Comment: If you were to use `$error=curl_error( $curl );` and then print that you would find `"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"` - the endpoint is `https` yet your code does not attempt to negotiate over SSL. If you modify the url to `http://....` then your code will return the json data as you expect but it would be better to continue using the SSL secured endpoint but configure curl correctly to do so.

Comment: Hi I still have no luck, I am on PHP 8.1 and the cURL still gives me 403 error...

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this, It's working fine.    



        

$curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.britishairways.com/solr/lpbd/lpfdestinations?fq=departure_city:LON+AND+arr_city_name_search:***+AND+trip_type:RT+AND+number_of_nights:7+AND+cabin:M&facet.pivot=arrival_city,is_sales_fare&facet=true',
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Please add explanation what was wrong with OP's approach

Comment: hi @sri-vijay, I have checked your code on https://phpsandbox.io/ and it still shows 403.

Comment: I'm not adding anything. I'm just running your code with the json_encode process. It's working fine for me.

Comment: I can see no difference here to the original - can you explain what you changed>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The reported problem is a 403 response from the remote server. Using exactly the same request code, but using `json_encode()` on the response won't change that.